# I am having uniswap problems

Tags: metamask, uniswap, ledger-nano-s

anyone have any idea what why I keep getting a "Gas estimation failed. Wait a few minutes and try again" message every time i try swapping a token on Uniswap. i am using metamask/ legder. i would appreciate any help.

Comment: This isn't tech support this is for coding.  Gas estimation fail is a generic thing returned for any error when trying to estimate gas, best guess, you didn't call approve first.

Comment: Having the same issue. Anyone solved this? Tried refreshing and diff browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying it on Goerli or Mainnet? I happen to face these issues too and assumed my contract had an issue. However, all it required was just a refresh of the uniswap page to make things work again, I believe it is buggy recently.

Comment: i am on mainnet still getting the same error . tired refreshing/ restarting still nothing